# Sprite doesn't change (and destroying)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted a bubble to explode, when it's clicked but it doesnt work somehow

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BCE : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite poppedSprite;
    public float destroyDelay = 1f;

    private bool isPopped = false;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Change the sprite to the "popped" sprite
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = poppedSprite;
        // Set the flag indicating that the bubble has been popped
        isPopped = true;
        // Destroy the GameObject after a short delay
        Destroy(this.gameObject, 0.1f);
    }
}
```

The bubble must change it's sprite and destroy (after 0.1 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that it's grabbing the proper gameObject. Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name)

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Change the sprite to the "popped" sprite
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = poppedSprite;
    // Set the flag indicating that the bubble has been popped
    isPopped = true;
    Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name)
    // Destroy the GameObject after a short delay
    Destroy(this.gameObject, 0.1f);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Honestly I would like to better be able to answer this and help revise the question so that a more direct approach can be found. My linkedin is on my profile, feel free to message me there.